# Running into 'authenticationrequired' error when using git lfs (Azure DevOps) behind a corporate (authenticated) proxy

Tags: git, azure, proxy, git-lfs

This issue only shows up when using LFS, not with normal git.

The environment is using a corporate proxy/firewall which does the SSL substitution for network scanning. The proxy requires authentication. In .gitconfig, to allow normal access, the following line was added:

```
[http "https://dev.azure.com"]
proxy = <corporateproxyaddress>
```

Testing git lfs, when pushing on an open network, this works fine. 
When running on the internal network, the following errors show up:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
batch response: Post https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: authenticationrequired
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS'
```

Note that on the open network, the message about locking does not show up.

Running this git_trace doesn't give a lot more information:

```
...
[Lots of other stuff]
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
< Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 12:39:31 GMT
< ActivityId: 78eab965-e1f6-454c-86f9-b0423b0d6874
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< X-VSS-E2EID: 78eab965-e1f6-454c-86f9-b0423b0d6874
< Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: C3D96E7AAAD34D31948B5780EFBEBD15 Ref B: AM3EDGE0805 Ref C: 2019-11-26T12:39:31Z
< Cache-Control: private
< X-TFS-Session: 78eab965-e1f6-454c-86f9-b0423b0d6874
< Content-Length: 149
< X-VSS-UserData: 0e251b3e-de99-6c32-a02e-8d195bc4322b:freek.giele@<organization>.com
< Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:c8f7fd9a-79c8-4464-b82d-4564078d0a8d
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< X-TFS-ProcessId: be11ea40-8903-40db-9a20-752174cabee1
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Request-Context
< 
* Closing connection 0
13:39:31.476453 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:39:31.489452 git.c:676               trace: exec: git-credential-manager store
13:39:31.490454 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager store
13:39:32.116456 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager store'
13:39:32.255452 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:39:32.269453 git.c:676               trace: exec: git-credential-manager store
13:39:32.269453 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager store
13:39:32.853455 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: .git/hooks/pre-push origin https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS
13:39:33.061456 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:39:33.076456 git.c:676               trace: exec: git-lfs pre-push origin https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS
13:39:33.076456 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-lfs pre-push origin https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS
13:39:33.447454 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
13:39:33.554492 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
13:39:33.825457 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '-l'
13:39:33.943456 trace git-lfs: pre-push: refs/heads/master bbcad77f7720f010e1c7dd6056167518866f9e20 refs/heads/master d84c8834fd3be49d2c3a859092771c51d0c4f1ac
13:39:37.437456 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/locks/verify
> POST /<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/locks/verify HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.azure.com
> Accept: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 36
> Content-Type: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> User-Agent: git-lfs/2.7.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.11.5; git 6b7fb6e3)
> 
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
13:39:37.877456 trace git-lfs: tq: running as batched queue, batch size of 100
13:39:37.883457 trace git-lfs: run_command: git rev-list --stdin --objects --not --remotes=origin --
13:39:37.995456 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 1
13:39:37.995456 trace git-lfs: api: batch 1 files
13:39:37.995456 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
> POST /<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/objects/batch HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.azure.com
> Accept: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 157
> Content-Type: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> User-Agent: git-lfs/2.7.1 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.11.5; git 6b7fb6e3)
> 
13:39:38.432491 trace git-lfs: api error: Post https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: authenticationrequired
batch response: Post https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: authenticationrequired
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s, done
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://<organization>@dev.azure.com/<organization>/DemoFolder/_git/LFS'
```

Is there a configuration setting I am missing or is this an issue with Git LFS?